# Can extensions have control for hiding context menus like Add Logpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

We are writing an vscode extension for debugging purpose
We would like to show 'Add Conditional Breakpoint' and 'Add Logpoint...' only on specific conditions
Can we achieve this
Please help

Comment: Got the answer.. thanks
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88962